# Devise Error : I18n::MissingInterpolationArgument at /users/sign_in for invalid user name and password

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, redirect, authentication, devise

I Have a `Devise` model(User). When I log in with a valid email and password then everything is working fine. but when the email or password is wrongly entered, instead of redirecting to the `Devise` login page with devise default error, I am getting a different error message

```
I18n::MissingInterpolationArgument at /users/sign_in
missing interpolation argument :authentication_keys in "Invalid %{authentication_keys} or password." ({:resource_name=>:user} given)
```

I don't know how to fix this. can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 3):

Although [Opeyemi Akinwoleola's hack](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37378699/100852) works, a better solution is to update to a more recent version of the devise gem (see also my response to this post: [Devise login error for invalid email or password is not working in rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37340962/devise-login-error-for-invalid-email-or-password-is-not-working-in-rails/38751814#38751814))

Answer (score 0):

I spent a while trying to solve this but this hack works for me.
Just head into locales/devise.en.yml and remove `%{authentication_keys}` from lines 12 and 15 and restart your server.