# Devise login error for invalid email or password is not working in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, devise

i have a devise `user` model. when the `user` enters wrong `password` its redirecting back to the login page by showing invalid email or password, this is working fine. but when the user enters the wrong `email` then i am not getting the same error. i am getting a different `error`

```
I18n::MissingInterpolationArgument at /users/sign_in
missing interpolation argument :authentication_keys in "Invalid %{authentication_keys} or password." ({:resource_name=>:user} given)
```

. in my user model i have a username field(this is unique). in my case a user can login with both `username` and `email`. is this `customisation` created any issue? this is my `devise.en.yml` file .

```
# Additional translations at https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/I18n

en:
  devise:
    confirmations:
      confirmed: "Your email address has been successfully confirmed."
      send_instructions: "You will receive an email with instructions for how to confirm your email address in a few minutes."
      send_paranoid_instructions: "If your email address exists in our database, you will receive an email with instructions for how to confirm your email address in a few minutes."
    failure:
      already_authenticated: "You are already signed in."
      inactive: "Your account is not activated yet."
      invalid: "Invalid email or password."
      locked: "Your account is locked."
      last_attempt: "You have one more attempt before your account is locked."
      not_found_in_database: "Invalid %{authentication_keys} or password."
      timeout: "Your session expired. Please sign in again to continue."
      unauthenticated: "You need to sign in or sign up before continuing."
      unconfirmed: "You have to confirm your email address before continuing."
    mailer:
      confirmation_instructions:
    subject: "Confirmation instructions"
      reset_password_instructions:
    subject: "Reset password instructions"
      unlock_instructions:
    subject: "Unlock instructions"
      password_change:
    subject: "Password Changed"
    omniauth_callbacks:
      failure: "Could not authenticate you from %{kind} because \"%{reason}\"."
      success: "Successfully authenticated from %{kind} account."
    passwords:
      no_token: "You can't access this page without coming from a password reset email. If you do come from a password reset email, please make sure you used the full URL provided."
      send_instructions: "You will receive an email with instructions on how to reset your password in a few minutes."
      send_paranoid_instructions: "If your email address exists in our database, you will receive a password recovery link at your email address in a few minutes."
      updated: "Your password has been changed successfully. You are now signed in."
      updated_not_active: "Your password has been changed successfully."
    registrations:
      destroyed: "Bye! Your account has been successfully cancelled. We hope to see you again soon."
      signed_up: "Welcome! You have signed up successfully."
      signed_up_but_inactive: "You have signed up successfully. However, we could not sign you in because your account is not yet activated."
      signed_up_but_locked: "You have signed up successfully. However, we could not sign you in because your account is locked."
      signed_up_but_unconfirmed: "A message with a confirmation link has been sent to your email address. Please follow the link to activate your account."
      update_needs_confirmation: "You updated your account successfully, but we need to verify your new email address. Please check your email and follow the confirm link to confirm your new email address."
      updated: "Your account has been updated successfully."
    sessions:
      signed_in: "Signed in successfully."
      signed_out: "Signed out successfully."
      already_signed_out: "Signed out successfully."
    unlocks:
      send_instructions: "You will receive an email with instructions for how to unlock your account in a few minutes."
      send_paranoid_instructions: "If your account exists, you will receive an email with instructions for how to unlock it in a few minutes."
      unlocked: "Your account has been unlocked successfully. Please sign in to continue."
  errors:
    messages:
      already_confirmed: "was already confirmed, please try signing in"
      confirmation_period_expired: "needs to be confirmed within %{period}, please request a new one"
      expired: "has expired, please request a new one"
      not_found: "not found"
      not_locked: "was not locked"
      not_saved:
    one: "1 error prohibited this %{resource} from being saved:"
    other: "%{count} errors prohibited this %{resource} from being saved:"
```

these are the devise and rails versions in `gemfile.lock` file.

```
    devise (3.2.4)
    devise-async (0.9.0)
    devise (~> 3.2)
    devise
    devise-async

    rails (4.1.5)
```

Comment: My issue was solved when I restarted the server after running the migrations. For some reason, the server cached something and would not accept the credentials.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define a virtual attribute called `login` for example in your user model and tell devise to use this field in `authentication_keys`.

Check this link for details
https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Allow-users-to-sign-in-using-their-username-or-email-address

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I solved it by updating to the latest version of devise (I am currently running 4.2.0). You might have to update your ruby version for the latest versions of devise to work.(https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#400rc1---2016-02-01)